How to Flush Left short-text in displayed formula elegantly?
In some mathematicas illstrution context, there exists some short text like "we can derived:" or "It is obviously that:", with a formula after them:
To make the context more fluent and squeeze more papar space, I want a method the typeset these Short-Text in the displayed formula line but be Flushed Left, with the original displayed formula be centered in the \textwidth.
I know the requirement may be not so reasonable: for the reason I don't use the inline formula instead, that is the small formula couldn't catch the attention of readers, and didn't show the step-by-step derivation as clearly as the displayed formula. And for the normal case, in my option, the only short text like "we can derive:" may take over one line, which looks not so elegant. And I have consulted the link and link, but the case is not the same, what I want is an automatical solution.
I fould that the problem is not so clearly, the case is that:

the layout of Single Short Text here take over one line is not so elegant, I want the shift the formula up as shown above;
However if the case is the long paragraph, or the single text is larger than half of \textwidth, I want the normal case(displayed in the next line) to use the displayed formula. Is there good method to ellinimate the space line with Short-Single-Text(?)
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
We know that: \[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\]
It's obviously that:
\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\]

We know that: \begin{align*}
\SwapAboveDisplaySkip \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align*} 
Thus we can derive that:
\begin{align*}
    \SwapAboveDisplaySkip a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{align*} 
It's obviously that:
\begin{align*}
    \SwapAboveDisplaySkip \SwapAboveDisplaySkip \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\shortintertext{We know that:} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\shortintertext{It's obviously that:}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align*}

\begin{tabular}{lp{0.34\textwidth}}
    We know that: & \hfill{ $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$} \hfill \\
    It's obviously that: & \hfill{ $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$} \hfill
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
% automatically adjust
\shortmaybeintertext{It's obviously}{\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]} % short flustleft and center

\shortmaybeintertext{That's }{\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\]} % short flustleft and center

\shortmaybeintertext{We can derive:}{\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\]} % short flustleft and center

\shortmaybeintertext{From the theorem and the difficulty that:}{\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\]} % long in one line:don't flushleft and normal with \[\]

\shortmaybeintertext{From the theorem and the difficulty with that from the theorem and the difficulty with that from the theorem and the difficulty with that:}{\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\]} % more than one line:don't flushleft and normal with \[\]

It's obviously:\\[-5ex]
\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]

\vspace*{3ex}

That's:\\[-7ex]
\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\]

\vspace*{3ex}

We can derive:\\[-4.8ex]
\[ \begin{aligned} 
    a^2 + b^2&=c^2 \\
    a^2 + b^2&=c^2 \\
    a^2 + b^2&=c^2
    \end{aligned}
\]

From the theorem and the difficulty that:
\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\]

From the theorem and the difficulty with that from the theorem and the difficulty with that from the theorem and the difficulty with that:
\[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n^2}}\]

\end{document}

What could be difficulty maybe the how to decide the \\[<dim>] above automtically according to the first height of the following displayed formula... Thanks!


Have you looked at the \intertext and \shortintertext macros?

\[... \]  and equation() automatically sets the space above to zero if the circumstances are just right. Envs like align does not. If align is not numbered you can use equation plus the aligned env to get the same effect.

Mathtools has a manual macro that can swap the space above an align. It's called SwapAboveDisplayskip or similar, see the Mathtools manual

@Mico Thanks to yr reply, I appended the case of \shortintertext, but the unwanted empty line with short-text remains.

Not much of help, but one option could be to put the short lines inside the upcoming formula, flushed left. ConTeXt example (sorry, not sure how to do it in LaTeX.) I cannot imagine you want this also for longer paragraphs where the last line just happen to be short, right?

Yes, whaat I want is elegant method to flush the short-text left in the formula, and vertically centered as you shown. Actually I don't want it for multiple text-lines paragraph now, this will change the space of the paragraph not consistency, I will change the question of the paragraph. Thanks.

what kind of syntax are you prepared to use? if you had something like \shortmaybeintertext{<text>}{<maths>} you could define that so it used \shortintertext if <text> exceeded, say, 75% of the available space, but typeset it flush left and inline otherwise. but I'm not sure if that would qualify as 'automatic' on your view?

Yes, I want syntax like \shortmaybeintertext{<text>}{<maths>} when I typeset some short-text formula inline with 75% of the available space. What I think "automatic" is the \shortmaybeintertext can detect whether 75% space left. The logic of judge the space get me stuck...

@cfr  I have append the example syntax and comments the ideal result after the question.

Maybe egreg and his hitmen will correct me on this, but I think an automatic solution isn’t really possible. I believe that the dimensions of something cannot be calculated until the input reaches the “stomach” of TeX, but we need this information already at the “mouth”. So I’d say: Stick to the manual solution. Judging this manually on a case-by-case basis is only going to take a couple of seconds each time:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\NewDocumentCommand{\leftintertext}{ m } {%
    &\mathrlap{\text{#1}}&%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    \leftintertext{We know that:}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} &\\
    \leftintertext{It's obvious that:}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
    \leftintertext{}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
    \leftintertext{We know that:}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
    \leftintertext{Thus we can derive that:}
    a^2+b^2&=c^2 \\
    \leftintertext{It's obviously that:}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
    \leftintertext{We know that:}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
    \leftintertext{It's obviously that:}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
    \leftintertext{We know that:}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
    \shortintertext{And now a very long text sentence before we repeat the formula for the trillionth time:}
    \leftintertext{}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}


If you absolutely want centered equations rather than equations aligned at the equality sign, you can probably use e.g. \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{lc} ... \end{IEEEeqnarray*} from IEEEtrantools. But then \shortintertext has to be replaced by \noalign{\noindent ...}.
EDIT: I can think of one possible automatic solution, but actually implementing it is out of my league. For this, we need to somehow rely on the line breaking in text mode. We need some horizontal phantom on the line of the text with width .25\linewidth. So if the text line is longer than .75\linewidth, then there will be a line break. And then if there is a line break, we somehow need this phantom to vanish. And furthermore, we need to make this line break produce the extra line before the math. But that is a job for the TeX gurus (if it’s even feasible at all). And at the end of the day, I still think it isn’t worth it. For math typesetting, manual fine-tuning is usually better than too much automation.

Oh, the usage of flalign actually satisfactory. I am not so familar with the mechanism about how the TeX goobled the formula aand typeset the height, but yr case is actually a possible solution. thanks uuuu.

Another curiosity is that why you have edited and deleted the \mathlrap, which shift the cursor back? And that cause the mismatch between the figure and code.

@Explorer Sorry, my bad, that was an error. I changed it back.
